# Binomial coefficient in Java

Tags: java, beginner, interview-questions

> Find nCr for given n and r.
>
> **Input:**
>
> First line contains no of test cases T, for every test case 2
>   integers as inputs (n,r).
>
> **Output:**
>
> Compute and print the value in separate line. Modulus your
>   output to 10^9+7. If n
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> 1<=T<=50
>
> 1<=n<=1000
>
> 1<=r<=800
>
> **Example:**
>
> Input:
>
> 1
>
> 3 2
>
> Output:
>
> 3

My approach:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class GFG {

    private static int calcBinCoeff (int num, int r) {

        BigInteger numerator = new BigInteger("1");
        int limit = (int)(Math.pow(10,9) + 7);
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(limit));

        for (int i = num; i > num - r ; i--) {
            BigInteger ind = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i));
            numerator = numerator.multiply(ind);
        }   

        BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("1");

        for (int i = 2; i <= r; i++) {
            BigInteger elem = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i));
            fact = fact.multiply(elem);
        }

        BigInteger ans = (numerator.divide(fact)).mod(modulus);

        return ans.intValue();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int numTests = sc.nextInt();

            while (numTests-- > 0) {
                int num = sc.nextInt();
                int r = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.println(calcBinCoeff(num, r));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have the following questions with regards to the above code:

1.Is there a smarter way to approach this question?

2. How can I improve the space and time complexity of the given question?
3. Have I gone too overboard by using BigInteger Library for this question?

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binomial-coefficient-dp-9/)

Answer (score 3):

- Is there a smarter way to approach this question?

We'll see in a moment. Parts of it can be improved for sure.

- How can I improve the space and time complexity of the given question?

You can't. The *complexity* will remain the same. The changes you can make might give small increases in performance or decrease memory usage, but the *complexity* will remain the same.

- Have I gone too overboard by using BigInteger Library for this question?

I thought at first that it was possible to use just `long`, but I'm afraid not. Because of 1000 nCr 500, and such big numbers, you are stuck with `BigInteger`.

---

You can use [BigInteger.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-) instead of using the constructor with a String.

You can save some time by using the symmetric property of nCr if r > n / 2. For example, 100 nCr 80 is the same as 100 nCr 20.

You can use just one for-loop instead of two:

```
value = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    value = value * (n - i) / (i + 1);
}
return value;
```

I used something similar in [a project of mine](https://github.com/Zomis/Minesweeper-Analyze/blob/ab97053049f9e94828fdc895f98f22f51600e0a0/src/main/java/net/zomis/minesweeper/analyze/Combinatorics.java#L94) (where I used `double` instead and thus didn't have to think about truncating integers - an issue which is fixed above thanks to Martin R).

Comment: Yes, 1000 choose 500 will overflow with long.

Comment: It should be `value = value * (n - i) / (i + 1);` so that the intermediate results are integers. But reducing `value = value % M` in each step could still produce a wrong result, try it with \$ \binom {10}{3} \bmod 17 \$.

Comment: @MartinR Right, in my own code I was using `double`. I think I fixed all your points now.

Comment: @aventurin Yeah I was fooled by the modulo requirement, but indeed it goes wrong because the value will be multiplied in the next iteration. Fixed that issue now.

Comment: @SimonForsberg: Actually it *is* possible, but you have to multiply with  the “modular inverse” of (i+1) instead of dividing by (i+1). (C code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35229199/1187415)

Comment: @MartinR Then it seems like I learned something new today. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @SimonForsberg. Also, great projects on Github!!

Answer (score 3):

Given the product formula

$$\binom nk = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{n-k+i}{i} \tag1$$

and the symmetry property

$$\binom nk = \binom n{n-k} \tag2$$

of the binomial coefficient, you can implement the calculation in the following way which avoids fractional intermediate values as well as looping more than \$\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor\$ times.

```
static final BigInteger MOD = BigInteger.valueOf(1_000_000_007L);

public static BigInteger calcBinCoeff(BigInteger n, BigInteger k)
{
    BigInteger bin; // binomial coefficient
    BigInteger nom; // nominator
    BigInteger den; // denominator

    if (k.shiftLeft(1).compareTo(n) == 1)
        return calcBinCoeff(n, n.subtract(k)); // (2)

    bin = BigInteger.ONE;
    nom = n;
    den = BigInteger.ONE;

    while (den.compareTo(k) < 1) // (1)
    {
        bin = bin.multiply(nom).divide(den);
        nom = nom.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        den = den.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    return bin;
}

// 159835829
calcBinCoeff(BigInteger.valueOf(1000), BigInteger.valueOf(800)).mod(MOD);
```

Using `long` would overflow for \$1000 \choose 500\$.

Instead of taking the result of `calcBinCoeff` modulo `MOD` you could modify the above code and calculate `bin` modulo `MOD` in each intermediate step. As @MartinR mentioned in a comment, division must then be replaced by multiplication with the modular inverse of the denominator. This works because 1000000007 is prime and thus coprime to any input in the given range.

```
public static BigInteger calcBinCoeff(BigInteger n, BigInteger k)
{
    BigInteger bin; // binomial coefficient
    BigInteger nom; // nominator
    BigInteger den; // denominator

    if (k.shiftLeft(1).compareTo(n) == 1)
        return calcBinCoeff(n, n.subtract(k));

    bin = BigInteger.ONE;
    nom = n;
    den = BigInteger.ONE;

    while (den.compareTo(k) < 1)
    {
        bin = bin.multiply(nom).multiply(den.modInverse(MOD)).mod(MOD);
        nom = nom.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        den = den.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    return bin.mod(MOD);
}
```

For the small prime modulus 1000000007 this algorithm also works for `long` without overflow. A possible implementation is given below.

```
public static long calcBinCoeff(long n, long k)
{
    long bin; // binomial coefficient
    long nom; // nominator
    long den; // denominator

    if (k + k > n)
        return calcBinCoeff(n, n - k);

    bin = 1;
    nom = n;
    den = 1;

    while (den <= k)
    {
        bin = Math.floorMod(bin * nom, MOD);
        bin = Math.floorMod(bin * modInverse(den, MOD), MOD);
        nom -= 1;
        den += 1;
    }

    return Math.floorMod(bin, MOD);
}

/**
 * The modular inverse as described in
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm
 * @param n A positive number.
 * @param p A prime number.
 * @return The modular inverse
 */
public static long modInverse(long n, long p)
{
    //  i-1   i
    long R,   r; // remainders
    long S,   s; // 1st Bézout coefficients
    long T,   t; // 2nd Bézout coefficients

    assert n > 0 && p > 0;

    R = n;
    r = p;

    S = 1;
    s = 0;

    T = 0;
    t = 1;

    while (r > 0)
    {
        long _q = R / r;
        long _r = R - _q * r;  R = r;  r = _r;
        long _s = S - _q * s;  S = s;  s = _s;
        long _t = T - _q * t;  T = t;  t = _t;
    }

    assert R == 1; // gcd == 1 since p is assumed to be prime

    return Math.floorMod(S, p);
}
```

Comment: I've overread the 10^9+7 modulus. With than limitation you could actually use `long` as @MartinR pointed out in another comment.

Comment: Thanks, @aventurin. That's a very good solution by the way. You have utilised the Math behind nicely.

Comment: Beginner question: Isn't using **global variables** considered bad coding practice, @aventurin?

Comment: Yes, generally speaking global variables are considered bad practice. This also holds for Java that does not have a global scope (every variable belongs to a class). An exception from this rule are constants, i.e. variables that could not be reassigned (ˋfinalˋ) and whose state could not be changed (immutable type such as ˋBigIntegerˋ). ˋMODˋ is such a case.

Answer (score 3):

> I have the following questions with regards to the above code:
>
> 1. Is there a smarter way to approach this question?
> 2. How can I improve the space and time complexity of the given question?
> 3. Have I gone too overboard by using BigInteger Library for this question?

Yes, as follows, and yes. Consider

> > Modulus your output to 10^9+7

You seem to have taken that instruction rather literally. Multiplication is not constant time when you're working with `BigInteger`. If all of the multiplications are carried out instead in `long`s modulo M=10^9+7 then they become effectively constant time.

This gives you two main options:

1. Compute the two values you currently compute, modulo M, and then use [extended Euclid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers) to compute a multiplicative inverse M (which is prime by design) to perform the division.
2. Use a simple sieve to compute the prime factorisation of each number up to n; then find the power of each prime independently as \$\nu_p \left(\binom{n}{r}\right) = \nu_p (n!) - \nu_p(r!) - \nu_p((n-r)!)\$ and \$\nu_p(k!) = \sum_{i=1}^k \nu_p(i) \$. Finally multiply together the appropriate prime powers modulo M.

Postscript: it occurs to me that if you take the first of these alternatives, using `BigInteger` *would* mean that you don't need to implement Euclid yourself, as you could use `BigInteger.modInverse`. It would still be advisable to apply `mod` frequently to keep the size of the integers down, but "to avoid reimplementing the wheel" is a good reason to use `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Taylor. This Math trick didn't enter my head that time!!